# Is it possible to create a custom provider that is also request scoped?

Tags: nestjs

I'd like to create a custom provider for a request-scoped resource, combining these styles:

https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/custom-providers#use-factory
https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/injection-scopes#request-provider

I'm not sure if it's possible, or what the correct markup of the custom provider is if so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact you can do that by passing the scope property along the factory

Here is the link to the interface
https://github.com/nestjs/nest/blob/master/packages/common/interfaces/modules/provider.interface.ts

Comment: Yes, also had to include the REQUEST symbol in the inject property array.

Comment: If you want access to the request then exact :)